# объясните как работает деструктор

Tags: php

```
<?php ## Базовый класс.
  class FileLogger
  {
    public $f;          // открытый файл
    public $name;       // имя журнала
    public $lines = []; // накапливаемые строки
    public $t;
    public function __construct($name, $fname)
    {
      $this->name = $name;
      $this->f = fopen($fname, "a+");
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
      fputs($this->f, join("", $this->lines));
      fclose($this->f);
    }
    public function log($str)
    {
      $prefix = "[".date("Y-m-d_h:i:s ")."{$this->name}] ";
      $str = preg_replace('/^/m', $prefix, rtrim($str));
      $this->lines[] = $str."\n";
    }
  }


$gg = new FileLogger('1', '2');
 echo $gg->log(1);
//echo $gg;
unset($gg);

//$gg->name = 314;
//$gg->f = 101;

//unset($gg);//  unset();
//$gg = new FileLogger;
//unset($gg);

?>
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что здесь __нет телепатов__? На какой строке выводится сообщение что не хватает аргументов? Почему из вас надо клещами информацию тянуть? Откройте уже справочный раздел, прочитайте все пункты, на носу зарубите.

Comment: я написал хочу понять как работает дескриптор

Comment: вам говорят. что если ошибка про аргументы, приведите текст ошибки. Вопрос то в чем, хотите понять как работает, или в чем ошибка? задавайте конкретный вопрос. Если есть текст ошибки, прилагайте к вопросу. Чтобы получить хороший ответ, надо задать хороший вопрос. и не путайте деструктор и дескриптор.

Comment: сдается мне, что такой логгер случае фатальной ошибки в лог ничего не запишет

Comment: я исправил, но не могу понять как работает деструктор

Comment: деструктор срабатывает когда вы "убиваете" экземпляр класса, в вашем случае в этот момент - `unset($gg);`. А как работает - что в нём напишите, так и будет работать.

Comment: я это понимаю, но хочу понять на практике. Если unset($gg); убрать все равно деструктор срабатывает

Comment: а куда он денется то? скрипт работу завершает, все объекты уничтожаются. при этом и деструктор вызван будет. Он будет вызван в любом случае, вопрос только в какой момент времени, во время работы скрипта, когда ссылки на объект пропадут, либо при завершении работы скрипта

Comment: а зачем он нужен если всегда будет работать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Деструктор вызывается при уничтожении объекта
2. Объект уничтожается, когда его счетчик ссылок становится равным нулю
3. Счетчик ссылок объекта увеличивается, когда мы присваиваем этот объект какой-то переменной
4. Счетчик ссылок уменьшается, когда переменной, которая хранила указатель на объект присваивают другое значение или она выходит из области видимости.
5. Глобальные переменные теряют видимость при завершении работы скрипта.

Пример (в комментариях значение счетчика ссылок):

```php
$obj1 = new ...  // 1
$obj2 = $obj1;   // 2
$obj1 = null;    // 1
func($obj2)      // 2 присвоили значение $arg
// 1 $arg ушла из области видимости

function func($arg) {
  $local = $arg; // 3
}                // 2 $local ушла из области видимости
```